# Is it a good idea to keep this views in a map?

Tags: java, android, performance, view, hashmap

I have a `RecyclerView` where I use a certain `ViewHolder`. One of my `ViewHolder` components is a `LinearLayout` where, for each list item, I have to add several views inside. The instantiation of each one of those (different) views is time-consuming and so, I have created a `HashMap<Integer, List<View>>` to save the reference of these views for each item depending on the index, thus not needing to initialize them again.

The thing is, I don't know if is correct to remove each one of the `LinearLayout` children and add all the views in each `onBindViewHolder()` call, or if there is a more efficient and elegant way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a good example offhand, but I suspect that's not a good approach. That map is going to continue to grow for every individual index, which will default the purpose of recycling views. What you most likely want to do here is use nested RecyclerViews, and share a common RecycledViewPool among them. See: https://proandroiddev.com/optimizing-nested-recyclerview-a9b7830a4ba7.

Comment: @kcoppock thank you!!